# An error when i try to build project Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

An error is

```
22:21   RuntimeException: No root duplication, roots=[C: (2), admin (4), ic_menu_share.png (779), R.java (830), xhtml11-model-1.mod (919), xhtml-inlstyle-1.mod (928), patch-vnu (1029), xhtml5core.rnc (1033), svg-style.rnc (1115), svg-clip.rnc (1122), SnmpString.java (1187), SnmpDefinitions.java (1193), JDMEnterprise.java (1258), JDMTrapInterestedHost.java (1264), GtkChildWindow.java (1329), GtkClipboardDelegate.java (1334), SnmpMibRequestImpl.java (1407), SnmpTableEntryNotification.java (1413), DispmanCursor.java (1510), OMAPX11Platform.java (1517), SnmpMsgProcessingSubSystem.java (1591), SnmpDecryptedPdu.java (1593), Repository.java (1676), regexp (1679), DOMOrder.java (1764), FastStringBuffer.java (1766), CatalogException.java (1843), ResolvingParser.java (1845), MgmtData.java (1921), KeyInfoContent.java (1923), X509IssuerSerialResolver.java (1999), DEREncodedKeyValueResolver.java (2001), MarkerStateListener.java (2080), NativeMedia.java (2082), BaseMarkupSerializer.java (2163), SerializerFactoryImpl.java (21... (show balloon)
```

I tried to Clean project but it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: can you show us complete log.I mean some more lines before and after this error Or this is the only thing you got?